Issue calling a variadic template constructor
The following code doesn't work, it fails because it cannot find a constructor with a <int, bool> signature.
I know can't specify explicitely the template parameters in the case of a constructor.
Why does it fail template parameter deduction? Is there any way to make it work? I know I can use a template factory instead of a constructor as a workaround (Which I will likely do, but I'm curious if it's doable with constructors only)
(Requires c++11 for delegating constructors)
template<size_t S>
struct Foo
{
    Foo() {}
    
    template<typename ... FirstArgsT, typename LastArgT>
    Foo(const FirstArgsT& ... FirstArgs, const LastArgT& LastArg) : Foo(FirstArgs...)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(FirstArgsT)+1<=S);
        TypeSizes[sizeof...(FirstArgsT)] = sizeof(LastArgT);
    }
        
    size_t TypeSizes[S];
};


int main()
{
    int arg1 = 3;
    bool arg2 = false;
    Foo<2> foo(arg1, arg2);  //error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo<2>::Foo(int&, bool&)’
    return 0;
}


The compiler cannot deduce LastArgT if it comes after the template parameter pack. You can either change your code to have the parameter pack at the end, or simply use pack expansion:
template<size_t S>
struct Foo
{
    template<typename ... ArgsT>
    Foo(const ArgsT& ... Args) : TypeSizes{sizeof(Args)...} { }
       
    std::array<size_t,S> TypeSizes;
};

This works as well with plain-arrays if you don't like to use std::array:
https://godbolt.org/z/a19GsW7as

Yes, I have the requirement not to use STL unfortunately... But I would have sworn it would not work with plain arrays.
Great solution, thanks!

@galinette That's a very odd requirement. size_t is part of the standard library too, but you are using that in your question, so where is the line drawn?

just provide the another solution mentioned by chtz.
#include <iostream>
template<size_t S>
struct Foo
{
    Foo() {}
    
    template<typename ... FirstArgsT, typename LastArgT>
    Foo(const LastArgT& LastArg, const FirstArgsT& ... FirstArgs) : Foo(FirstArgs...)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(FirstArgsT)+1<=S);
        TypeSizes[sizeof...(FirstArgsT)] = sizeof(LastArgT);
    }
        
    size_t TypeSizes[S];
};


int main()
{
    int arg1 = 3;
    bool arg2 = false;
    Foo<2> foo(arg2, arg1);
    return 0;
}


This requires changing the parameter order when constructing Foo (which is likely inconvenient for OP). With a bit more code, it is of course possible to work around that, but I did not bother to do that, since there is a much simpler solution. (e.g., (TypesSizes[S-1-sizeof...(FirstArgsT)]=sizeof(LastArgT); -- but this additionally needs to handle the case that S is larger than the number of arguments)
